# bash - finding unexpected user accounts

Tags: bash

I have a great line to list all the user accounts, but how do I tell if one of them is NOT expected to be in the list.

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1

fred 
barney
wilma
elroy_jetson
```

I don't expect Elroy Jetson to be in Bedrock, so I want to raise a flag.
The only way I can think of to do it seems clumsy:

```
ALL_USERS_ARE_VALID="true"
for USER in `cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1`; do
  if [[ "$USER" == "fred" ]]; then
    #valid user
  elif [[ "$USER" == "barney" ]]; then
    #valid user
  elif [[ "$USER" == "wilma" ]]; then
    #valid user
  else
    ALL_USERS_ARE_VALID="false"
  fi
done
```

There's gotta be a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:> cat expectedResidents
fred 
barney
wilma
:> cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1| fgrep -vf expectedResidents
elroy_jetson
```

`fgrep` means *file*grep, where file contains the targets you are searching for. Note that traditional fgrep only supports exact string matching (and the the `-i` ignore-case) option, so trailing spaces etc. in you searchlist file will cause problems. Using the `-v` option, as usual, means ignore lines that match the specified patterns. `-f` tells `fgrep` which file to use. Finally, for traditional `fgrep`s (Sun, etc), there are limitings to how many lines can be in the searchlist file, so if this is for large production system, test, test, test ;-)

Depending on your OS, you may need to figure out if you need to use `grep -F -vf ...` or similar instead.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I like this option since it works as a one liner.  The "case" approach works well too.

Comment: I like `case` comparisons for many things, but using an searchlist file makes your process more configuration driven. Please note my edit, 'Finally ..'. AND thanks for the chk-mark!

Answer (score 1):

How would you expect the computer to know elroy shouldnt be in bedrock? If you have a list of "known" valid accounts, have a file of them, and do `grep -v` which says find whats not these..

Comment: I have 5 known accounts and there will never be any others.  How would I use grep -v?   grep -v "fred barney wilma" `cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1` ??

Answer (score 1):

A better way to write the chained if statements would be using a case construct as follows:

```
case "$USER" in
  fred|barney|wilma)
    # valid user
    ;;
  *)
    ALL_USERS_ARE_VALID="false"
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple if statements, store your valid users in a file then do a comparison using `comm`.

Example:

```
$ cat valid_users # file containing valid users
fred 
barney
wilma

$ comm -23 <(cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1 | sort) <(sort valid_users)
elroy_jetson
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case in` statement.

For e.g.:

```
case `cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1` in
        fred | barney | wilma )
                # valid
        ;;
        *)
                echo "Unallowed user";
                break;
        ;;
esac;
```